# Changing angularjs view resets elements attributes

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an angular app with root page,

```
    <script>
       $('#myAppView').css("height", "500px");
    </script>

<div data-ng-app="app">
    <div id="myAppView" data-ng-view="">
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine when I load my first view into it using routing, but when I change that view using `<a href="#/differentView"` it removes `height` property from my element `myAppView`

Any idea why this happens ?

I don't want to add jQuery to every view to get the height for my partial views.

***I know I can add a parent div to myAppView div to achieve what I want, but is there any better alternative ?***

**Edit**

I think the issue is that my jquery is adding height to the element not editing the css class

Comment: This is invalid style you need to use selector like `#myAppView { height: 500px; }`

Comment: @jcubic it was just a typo, fixed it question,

Comment: you styled a class, and in the html you have an id. Another typo?

Comment: @Bata Yes, thanks I fixed it again, my first view works perfectly, issue comes when I switch views

Comment: Can you show some code of the views?

Comment: @A.Romeu they are almost empty

Comment: Why don't you assign the property on css directly instead of using jQuery?

Comment: @A.Romeu because I am doing something too far complex and above code is just an example

Comment: is it possible for you to define a class and toggle that class in your element when you open the view you want through `ng-click` ?